# Removing a message that is being redelivered

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I have a set up of an ActiveMQ broker and a single consumer. Consumer gets a message that he is not able to process because a service that it depends has a bug (once fixed it will be fine). So the message keeps being redelivered (consumer redelivery) - we use JMS sessions. With our current configuration it will keep redelivering it every 10 minutes for 1 day. That obviously causes a problem because other messages are not being consumed.

In order to solve this problem I have accessed the queue through JMX and tried to delete that message but it is not there. I guess it is cached on the consumer and not visible at the broker.
Is there any way to delete this message other than restarting the application?

Is it possible to configure the redelivery mechanism so that such message (that causes a live lock eventually) is put at the end of the queue so that other messages can be processed?

The 10 minutes for 1 day redelivery policy should stay as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting jms.nonBlockingRedelivery=true on the connection factory resolved the problem. Now even if there is a message redelivered it does not block processing of other Messages.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're right that the messages are stuck in the consumer's prefetch buffer, and I don't know of a way to delete them from there.

I'd change your redelivery policy to send to the DLQ after the second failure, with a much shorter interval between them, like 30 seconds, and I'd configure the DLQ strategy as an `individualDeadLetterStrategy` so you get a separate DLQ containing only messages from this particular queue.  Then set up a consumer on this DLQ to move the messages to (the end of) the main queue whenever your reprocessing condition is met (whether that's after a certain delay, or based on reading some flag value from a database, or whatever).  This consumer is where you'd implement "every 10 minutes for 1 day" logic, instead of in the redelivery policy where you currently have it.

That will keep the garbage ones out of the main queue so they don't delay other messages from being consumed, but still ensure that they will be reprocessed later.  And it will put them on the broker instead of in the consumer's prefetch buffer, where you can view and delete them.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get it to the back of the queue is to reproduce it to the queue. Redelivery polices can only be configured down to the destination on the connection factory.

Given that you already have a connection, it shouldn't be to hard to create a producer that can either move the given message to a DLQ or produce it back to the queue when you run into that particular bug.